# Alternate letters to UpperCase

Tags: strings, unit-testing, go, rags-to-riches, unicode

As an exercise I repeated this Java question, but in Go: [Convert string to mixed case](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/127135/convert-string-to-mixed-case)

The objective is for every second letter to be converted to uppercase.

Go string processing is relatively new to me, and I am looking for feedback on the use of the `unicode` package, any other go language or library features I should be using, and of course, issues with style, convention, or possible bugs.

I have put the following [in the playground as well](https://play.golang.org/p/9JP_7DbcRi).

```
package kata

import (
    "unicode"
)

// AlternateCase will return the input string modified such that alternate letters are transformed to uppercase.
//
// Note that non-letters are ignored, so in the input string `a!b` the `!` is ignored, so `b` is the second letter.
// The result of AlternateCase on `a!b` is `A!b`.
func AlternateCase(input string) string {
    runes := make([]rune, 0, len(input))
    var upper bool
    for _, c := range input {
        if unicode.IsLetter(c) {
            upper = !upper
            if upper {
                c = unicode.ToUpper(c)
            }
        }
        runes = append(runes, c)
    }
    return string(runes)
}
```

I have also written some test cases, and a documentation example:

```
package kata

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestAlternateCase(t *testing.T) {
    cases := []struct{ input, output string }{
        {"hello, world!", "HeLlO, wOrLd!"},
        {"a!b", "A!b"},
        {"AAAA", "AAAA"},
        {"", ""},
        {"h", "H"},
        {"!h", "!H"},
        {"日本語", "日本語"},
        {"f日u本b語ar", "F日U本B語Ar"},
    }
    for _, c := range cases {
        got := AlternateCase(c.input)
        if got != c.output {
            t.Errorf("For input '%v' expect '%v' but got '%v'", c.input, c.output, got)
        }
    }
}

func ExampleAlternateCase() {
    hi := "hello, world!"
    fmt.Printf("The AlternateCase of '%v' is '%v'\n", hi, AlternateCase(hi))
    // Output: The AlternateCase of 'hello, world!' is 'HeLlO, wOrLd!'
}
```

I am looking for feedback on the test mechanisms as well.

Comment: Could you explain the last two test examples that involve Chinese characters? Are the Chinese characters being included in the case alternation? I am especially wondering about the one with fubar -> FUBAr.

Comment: Example taken from the lower part of the page: https://blog.golang.org/strings Note that [unicode `U+65E5`](http://unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=65e5) is part of the Letter class (See: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/65e5/index.htm ) `Character.IsLetter()` is "yes"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think both your solution and your testing are fine.

A couple of test cases I would add (but your solution also passes them):

- a `string` starting with BOM, e.g. `{"\xef\xbb\xbfhi", "\xef\xbb\xbfHi"}`
- a `string` which is not a valid UTF-8 `string`, e.g. `{"h\xffi", "H\xef\xbf\xbdi"}`
- a `string` with multiple invalid UTF-8 bytes, e.g. `{"h\xff\xffi", "H\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbdi"}`

Explaining the invalid UTF-8 `string`s: Since you are converting your input string to `rune`s, invalid UTF-8 bytes are reported as a value of `0xfffd` (the Unicode replacement character), which when encoded as UTF-8 (happens when you convert `[]rune` back to `string`) results in a sequence of `[]byte{0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd}`; this is what the invalid `0xff` byte is compared to in the test case.

Performance wise I would use a `string` => `[]rune` conversion as you not only need the `rune`s, but you also want to convert them back to a `string`. Using `append()` is slower, and it has to assign a slice value (a descriptor) at each `rune`.

Also note that if we convert the `string` to `[]rune`, we only need to assign (overwrite) new runes which are converted to their upper case:

This is how I would do it:

```
func AlternateCase(s string) string {
    rs, upper := []rune(s), false
    for i, r := range rs {
        if unicode.IsLetter(r) {
            if upper = !upper; upper {
                rs[i] = unicode.ToUpper(r)
            }
        }
    }
    return string(rs)
}
```